# how to upload contract using substrate-front-end-template

Tags: smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

I am new to substrate.  As you can see, I have the front-end running, I can access the wasm file I want to upload, etc, but I don't know if I have the correct selections, and especially: what goes in the `code` entry box?

[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, `code` here means the contract code from your `.wasm` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read the following tutorials:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts

Typically the process is as follows:

1. Write your smart contract using [ink!](https://github.com/paritytech/ink)
2. Build your ink! smart contract using [cargo-contract](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract) CLI tool (you could even upload using this tool)
3. Use [contracts-ui](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui) or [polkadotJS apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer) or similar to upload/instantiate your ink! smart contract

Below you have [polkadotJS apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer) and [contracts-ui](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui) respectively. Notice how there is a file upload where you either upload the Wasm file or in the [contracts-ui](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui) interface you upload the contracts file (which also includes the Wasm for the contract along with some additional metadata).

[polkadotJS apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer)
[image]

In the above notice how once the Wasm is uploaded, you get the highlighted `code`. This is the `code` that your substrate-front-end-template is asking for. You can copy that, add a `0x` prefix, and paste it in your substrate-front-end-template and it should work. You can confirm by looking in chain state > contracts > codeStorage.

[contracts-ui](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui)
[image]

Notice how the contracts file also includes the Wasm.

[image]

Remember that regardless of which UI you use, you will need the underlying substrate node to be running the [contracts pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts). You can either configure this pallet into your node yourself or you can use the pre-configured [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node).